# tensorflow: "trying to mutate a frozen object", bazel

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, bazel

MacOS high sierra, MBP 2016, in terminal.

I'm following the directions here:
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/syntaxnet
All options for ./configure chosen as default (and all python directories double-checked.). All steps have completed cleanly until this:

```
bazel test ...
# On Mac, run the following:
bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names \
  dragnn/... syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
```

I assume I'm supposed to run the latter line ("bazel test --linkopt" etc.).  But I get the same result either way, interestingly.

This throws about 10 errors, each of the same type "trying to mutate a frozen object", and concludes tests not run, error loading package dragnn/protos, and couldn't start build.

This is the general form of the errors:

> syntaxnet>> bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names
>   dragnn/... syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
>
> .
>
> ERROR:
>   /Users/XXX/Desktop/NLP/syntaxnet/models/research/syntaxnet/dragnn/protos/BUILD:35:1:
>   Traceback (most recent call last): File
>   "/Users/XXX/Desktop/NLP/syntaxnet/models/research/syntaxnet/dragnn/protos/BUILD",
>   line 35 tf_proto_library_py(name = "data_py_pb2", srcs = ["dat..."])
>   File
>   "/Users/XXX/Desktop/NLP/syntaxnet/models/research/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/syntaxnet.bzl",
>   line 53, in tf_proto_library_py py_proto_library(name = name, srcs =
>   srcs, srcs_versi...", <5 more arguments>) File
>   "/private/var/tmp/_bazel_XXX/f74e5a21c3ad09aeb110d9de15110035/external/protobuf_archive/protobuf.bzl",
>   line 374, in py_proto_library py_libs += [default_runtime] trying to
>   mutate a frozen object ERROR: package contains errors: dragnn/protos

---

... [same error for various 'name = "...pb2"' files] ...

> INFO: Elapsed time: 0.709s FAILED: Build did NOT complete successfully
>   (17 packages loaded) ERROR: Couldn't start the build. Unable to run
>   tests

Any idea what could be doing this?  Thanks.

Comment: what is your bazel version? How did you install it?

Comment: asking because there is [this issue](https://github.com/bazelbuild/BUILD_file_generator/pull/30) which was fixed Nov 1 2017

Comment: brew install bazel

Comment: Will check this out. Thanks!!! I did brew install and brew upgrade tonight, so not sure if the commit that fixed that issue was caught by my install. I’ll find out. Thanks.

Comment: yeah, you could compile from source [as described here](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/install-compile-source.html) but instead of downloading the package you'd need to clone from git

Answer (score 5):

This error indicates a bug in the `py_proto_library` rule implementation.

`tf_proto_library_py` is defined in [`syntaxnet.bzl`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/5a5d330539dff11eef79ca2e716fb477baf13cf9/research/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/syntaxnet.bzl#L52). It is a wrapper around [`py_proto_library`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/5a5d330539dff11eef79ca2e716fb477baf13cf9/research/syntaxnet/syntaxnet/syntaxnet.bzl#L17), which is defined by the [`tf_workspace`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/5a5d330539dff11eef79ca2e716fb477baf13cf9/research/syntaxnet/WORKSPACE#L21) macro's [`protobuf_archive`](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/c52cdc03a67ceae9ecc8c00025d3c60f54833e2d/tensorflow/workspace.bzl#L360) rule.

"protobuf_archive" downloads Protobuf 3.3.0, which contains `//:protobuf.bzl` with the buggy `py_proto_library` rule implementation: in line #374 it tries to mutate an immutable object `py_libs`.

Make sure you **use the latest Bazel version**, currently that's 0.8.1.

If the problem still persists, then:

- I suggest filing a bug with:

  - Protobuf, to fix the `py_proto_library` rule
  - TensorFlow, to update their Protobuf version in `tf_workspace`, and
  - Syntaxnet to update their TF submodule reference in [`//research/syntaxnet`](https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/research/syntaxnet) to the bugfixed version.
- As a workaround, perhaps you can patch `protobuf.bzl`.

The patch is to change these lines:

```
   373    if default_runtime and not default_runtime in py_libs + deps:
   374      py_libs += [default_runtime]
   375
   376    native.py_library(
   377        name=name,
   378        srcs=outs+py_extra_srcs,
   379        deps=py_libs+deps,
   380        imports=includes,
   381        **kargs)
```

to these:

```
   373    if default_runtime and not default_runtime in py_libs + deps:
   374      py_libs2 = py_libs + [default_runtime]
   375    else:
   376      py_libs2 = py_libs
   377
   378    native.py_library(
   379        name=name,
   380        srcs=outs+py_extra_srcs,
   381        deps=py_libs2+deps,
   382        imports=includes,
   383        **kargs)
```

Disclaimer: this is a "blind" fix; I have not tried whether it works.

Comment: I compiled a fresh binary of 0.8.1 last night and got the same error, so I will try this “blind fix” tonight. Thanks for the suggestion!!!

Comment: That got me past that bug; there was a following nearly identical bug regarding cc_libs += [default_runtime], and then one with apple_cc_toolchain Xcode version, then "execvp(external/local_config_cc/wrapped_clang, ...)": Permission denied, then another and another.  Just a rabbit hole.

Comment: How far did you get?

Comment: I cleaned everything up, went back to Bazel 0.5.4, which has been recommended, and did all the steps again. Syntaxnet eventually compiled, but running eg demo.sh --conll crashed it, the tutorials were having a ton of problems with import graph_builder, and so forth. For now doing development in a Docker container, which is a pain, but I’ll try compiling again soon.

Answer (score 0):

```
Tried same pattern patch for cc_libs. 

  if default_runtime and not default_runtime in cc_libs:
    cc_libs2 = cc_libs + [default_runtime]
  else:
    cc_libs2 = cc_libs
  if use_grpc_plugin:
    cc_libs += ["//external:grpc_lib"]

  native.cc_library(
      name=name,
      srcs=gen_srcs,
      hdrs=gen_hdrs,
      deps=cc_libs2 + deps,
      includes=includes,
      **kargs)
```

Shows new error, but keeps compiling. (Ubuntu 16 on Windows System for Linux--don't ask, native tensorflow 1.4 winx64 works, but not syntaxnet).

greg@FX11:/mnt/c/code/models/research/syntaxnet$ bazel test ...
ERROR: /home/greg/.cache/bazel/_bazel_greg/adb8eb0eab8b9680449366fbebe59ec2/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD:451:1: in _transitive_hdrs rule @org_tensorflow//tensorflow/core/kernels:bounds_check_lib_gather:
Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "/home/greg/.cache/bazel/_bazel_greg/adb8eb0eab8b9680449366fbebe59ec2/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/core/kernels/BUILD", line 451
                _transitive_hdrs(name = 'bounds_check_lib_gather')
        File "/home/greg/.cache/bazel/_bazel_greg/adb8eb0eab8b9680449366fbebe59ec2/external/org_tensorflow/tensorflow/tensorflow.bzl", line 869, in _transitive_hdrs_impl
                set()

Just changed set() to depset() and that seems to have avoided the error.

Answer (score 0):

To make a long story short. I was inspired by a [sstrasburg](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1858731/sstrasburg)'s comment.

Firstly, uninstall a fresh version of bazel.

```
brew uninstall bazel
```

Download bazel 0.5.4 from [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/releases).

```
chmod +x bazel-0.5.4-without-jdk-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
./bazel-0.5.4-without-jdk-installer-darwin-x86_64.sh
```

After that, again run

```
bazel test --linkopt=-headerpad_max_install_names dragnn/... syntaxnet/... util/utf8/...
```

Finally, I got

> Executed 57 out of 57 tests: 57 tests pass.